# Defing record, field undefined

Tags: erlang, record

I'm kind of new to Erlang and still learning. I check the documentation (http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/records.html) but still can't get records to work.

```
 spawn(fun() -> loop(v2, #state{max = 3}) end).
```

As i understand the documentation this should work. atom = value to define a field in a record. Yet when I compile the code i get this error.

> simple.erl:10: field max undefined in record state

What I'm a doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Be sure you're setting a record definition in your module:

```
-record(state, {max}).
```

The record module attribute is described at the top of the Erlang reference link you posted.